# Convert a given array with all zeros to a target array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, segment-tree

Recently I came across an interview question. I tried solving it but interviewer was looking for a better solution. The question is:

> Given a source array containing zeroes and target array containing
>   numbers, return the smallest number of steps in which you can obtain
>   target from source.  You are only allowed to do following operation:
>   You can increase the values of source array elements each by 1 from
>   index L to index R in one operation.

My thoughts:

```
Let array be [4,2,3,5] 
cnt=0;
For each sub-array with only non-zero element, subtract minimum of that sub-array from each of the element of that sub-array. Count increases by sum of mins in each subarray
So array becomes :
After first step : [2,0,1,3] cnt+=1*2 (because only one subarray)
After second step : [0,0,0,2] cnt+=2+1 (because two subarray, each requiring an increment operation)
After second step : [0,0,0,0] cnt+=2
```

Can some one help in finding better algorithm? I am also thinking if segment tree / binary index tree could also be used but couldn't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of incrementing the zero array and transform it into given array, attack other way around - try to make given array into zero array by decrementing.

- Build a segment tree on top of the given array. The segment tree should be able to answer this queries - `min(left, right )` - index of minimum item between range `left` and `right`.
- Start with `range(0, n - 1)` where `n` is the size of the array. At any moment, for the `query(left, right)` lets say the minimum element is `x` and the index is `indx`.
- Now here is the trick. The idea is to NOT decrementing elements between range `left` to `right` practically because that will be difficult. Call recursively for `range(left, indx - 1)` and `range(indx + 1, right)`. For left part and right part now you know, you have already decremented `dx` from every element. So now for any element is `X`, you have to handle this like `X - dx`.

Hope you get the idea. I am going to provide C++ implementation for this.

### EDIT

Please see the code and use pen & paper. You will get the idea hopefully. I've added comment on the tricky part.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> segmentTree;
    vector<int> arr;
    int n;
    void init() {
        segmentTree.clear();
        const int SIZE  = pow(2, ceil(log((double) n) / log(2.0)) + 1) - 1;
        segmentTree.resize(SIZE, 0);
        build(1, 0, n - 1);
    }

    // O(n)
    int build(int node, int left, int right) {
        if(left == right) {
            return segmentTree[node] = left;
        }
        int leftNode = node << 1;
        int rightNode = leftNode | 1;
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        int leftIdx = build(leftNode, left, mid);
        int rightIdx = build(rightNode, mid + 1, right);
        return segmentTree[node] = (arr[leftIdx] <= arr[rightIdx]) ? leftIdx : rightIdx;
    }

    int query(int node, int left, int right, int x, int y) {
        if(x > right or y < left) return -1;
        if(left >= x and right <= y) return segmentTree[node];
        int leftNode = node << 1;
        int rightNode = leftNode | 1;
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        int leftIdx = query(leftNode, left, mid, x, y);
        int rightIdx = query(rightNode, mid + 1, right, x, y);
        if(leftIdx == -1) return rightIdx;
        if(rightIdx == -1) return leftIdx;
        return (arr[leftIdx] <= arr[rightIdx]) ? leftIdx : rightIdx;
    }

    int query(int x, int y) {
        return query(1, 0, n - 1, x, y);
    }

    int convertUtil(int left, int right, int dx) {
        if(left > right) return 0;
        int mid = query(left, right);
        int minElement = arr[mid];

        int cnt = 0; // the number of operation

        // dx is the amount that has been already decremented from this range
        // So you have to treat every element X as (X - dx)
        cnt += (minElement - dx);

        cnt += convertUtil(left, mid - 1, minElement) + convertUtil(mid + 1, right, minElement);

        return cnt;
    }

    int convert(vector<int>& arr) {
        this->arr = arr;
        this->n = arr.size();
        init();
        return convertUtil(0, n - 1, 0);
    }
};

// vector<int> arr {4,2,3,5};
// cout << Solution().convert(arr); // OUTPUT: 7
```

Comment: Could you please share on how the update function could be done efficiently. I mean decreasing each element by one will cause the segment tree to change (all elements) which I believe will be costly operation

Comment: @crystal Please check the code I've added just now. Actually you won't need the `update` method which will make it costly. Please check the code and let me know if you need any explanation. I am going to update my answer as well

Comment: Thanks alot for such detailed explanation :D

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple O(n) runtime, O(1) memory solution to this.

Consider the `target` array as a mountain-range with given heights. The minimum number of operations is the number of non-disconnected, 1-height layers you would have to put down to build that mountain-range.

But an easier way to think about that is as the total distance you would have to climb *up* if you traverse that mountain-range from either direction.

Here's a C++ implementation.

```
int minNumberOperations(const vector<int>& target) {
  int result = 0, prev = 0;
  for (int height : target) {
    result += max(0, height - prev);
    prev = height;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: what is val here ?

Comment: @AishwatSingh: Oops, nice catch! That was supposed to say `height`. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stack. Running time is O(moves + length).

Every time the value increases by 1, add (position, end_val) to the stack. Every time the value decreases by 1, remove the top element of the stack and pair its position with one to the left of your current position.

E.g., [5, 3, 2, 5]

```
process 5: an increase. Stack is now (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (0,5)
process 3: a decrease at index 1. Remove the top two elements from the stack and record these moves (0,0) (0,0). The stack is now (0,1), (0,2), (0,3)
process 2: a decrease at index 2. Remove the top element from the stack and record (0,1). The stack is now (0,1), (0,2)
process 5: an increase at index 3. The stack is now (0,1), (0,2), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5)
process 0 (implied): a decrease at index 4. record (3,3), (3,3), (3,3), (0,3), (0,3)
```

Final moves: (0,0) (0,0), (0,1), (3,3), (3,3), (3,3), (0,3), (0,3).

You can do better on space by recording multi-level position changes singly (e.g. (0,5) for the first move), but the time efficiency is the same because each move can only change the value by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public int minNumberOperations(int[] target) {
    int ans = target[0];
    for(int i=1; i < target.length; i++){
        if(target[i]>target[i-1]){
            ans += target[i]-target[i-1];
        }
    }
    return ans;
 }
```